# Error comparing Int array slice elements in Swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: arrays, swift, element, slice

In my playground in Xcode 9

```
func somefn<Int>(_ a:[Int])->[Int]{
    if(a.count == 1 || a.isEmpty){
        return a
    }else{
        let e1 = (a.count/2) - 1
        let s2 = e1 + 1

        let lhs = Array(a[...e1])
        let rhs = Array(a[s2...])

        if lhs.first! > rhs.first! {
            print("LHS first is bigger than RHS second")
        }

        return []
    }
}

let s = [1,4,6,9]
somefn(s)
```

Gives error:

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands

Comment: The problem goes away if you removed the `<Int>` just after `somefn`.

Comment: @rmaddy - very good spot but why? Its legit  syntax

Comment: @user2845005 Not sure why it is causing a problem but why did you add the `<Int>`?

Comment: Just saw the edit history where it doesn't have that <Int>

Comment: I had the same error when pasting it into an app.  Also, when asking Xcode for the type of lhs.first!, it says it's an Int without making it a blue link.  It's like it's not a real Int.

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh yeah. Before I fixed the indentation, the `<Int>` wasn't appearing because it looks like an HTML tag.

Comment: It was originally added as <T>  along with a[T] to make the function generic. But I was getting desperate so I changed it all to Int which meant that <Int> was actually redundant but left in. I would hazard this is a bug in Swift Generics.

Comment: @rmaddy what it is happening there is that OP is creating a new `Int` generic type which is shadowing the native Int type

Comment: @LeoDabus Excellent since I was typing up that exact answer. I'm just now seeing your comment after posting my answer which confirms what I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the `<Int>` syntax after the function name is being treated as a generic type placeholder and not the actual data type of `Int`.

If you replace `<Int>` with `T` in the whole function declaration you still get the error.

```
func somefn<T>(_ a:[T]) -> [T] {
```

This makes sense since the `<` operator is now ambiguous. By updating the signature to indicate that `T` must be a `Comparable`, the problem goes away:

```
func somefn<T:Comparable>(_ a:[T]) -> [T] {
```

You could also do:

```
func somefn<Int:Comparable>(_ a:[Int]) -> [Int] {
```

but that's confusing to any reader since that `Int` is not the data type of `Int`.

This all assumes you intend to be able to pass arrays of different data types and get back an array of the same type.

If you just want to support an array of `Int` for both the parameter and return type, change the signature to:

```
func somefn(_ a:[Int]) -> [Int] {
```